# Calculator to execute loop until "exit"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got to do this calculator on python 3 that must execute on loop until the user types `exit`. Besides, programming ahead of the user typing **invalid characters**, such as letters when asked to type an operator or a number.

I must use `while`, `if`... However, **I cannot use `import`**.

```
while True:

    operator = input("Give me an operator or \"exit\" to stop : ")

    if operator == "exit":
        break
    if operator != "+" or "-" or "*" or "/":

        print ("You must enter an operator")
        break
    no1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    no2 = input("Enter a number: ")
    if operator == "+":
        output = int(num1) + int(num2)
    elif operator == "-":
        output = int(num1) - int(num2)
    elif operator == "*":
        output = int(num1) * int(num2)
    else :
        output = int(num1) / int(num2)
    print("The result is " + str(result))
print("See you soon!")
```

I expect it to actually not stop when we enter anything but an operator, I want it to loop back to:

```
operator = input("Give me an operator or \"exit\" to stop : ")
```

Comment: simply replace the second `break` by `continue`

Comment: Watch out in this line : `operator = input("Give me an operator or \"exit\" to stop : ")` as you should get an `EOF` error.

Comment: You need to use a [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) statement (instead of `break` which terminates the loop).

Comment: Your condition is broken have a look to my awser.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! But still i have a problem: I want that when it's asked for a number and we enter a letter or operator it says something like "You must enter a number" and it goes back to ask for a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find below this your code that work as expected, however lets  start with general rules.

- Be attentif, when you declare a variable, use the same elsewhere in your code.
- Test, simple part of your code before trying to do a script. You condition to test operator was totally broken.

```py
while True:

    operator = input("Give me an operator or \"exit\" to stop : ")

    if operator == "exit":
        break
    if operator not in [ "+", "-", "*" , "/"]: #<== here you condition is wrong ,do this instead

        print ("You must enter an operator")
        continue
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Enter a number: ")) #
        num2 = int(input("Enter a number: ")) # <== both of this variable are not use else where ,rename to be consitdnt with the rest of your code
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer") 
    if operator == "+":
        output = num1 + num2
    elif operator == "-":
        output = num1 - num2
    elif operator == "*":
        output = num1 * num2
    else :
        output = num1 / num2
    print("The result is " + str(output)) #<=== here also, results was not defined 
print("See you soon!")
```

Comment: But what can I do so that when it's asked for a number and we enter a letter or operator it says something like "You must enter a number" and it goes back to ask for a number?

Comment: Updated, use isalnum.

Comment: I can't use isalnum. Is there any way tho make it something like: if not int(num1 and num2) : print ("Please enter an intenger") ??

Comment: @RayCactus could you use a try except block?

Comment: I can, please tell me how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Put a generic **`else`** statement which will continue with the next iteration.

```
if condition1 :
  //logic
elif condition2 :
  //logic
else:
  continue
```

Comment: My problem now is at:  if operator != "+" or "-" or "*" or "/":
print ("You must enter an operator") . Something is not working in this block, because even when i write a valid operator it still prints "You must enter an operator" and it goes on asking for a number. how do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are doing:
`if operator != "+" or "-" or "*" or "/":`
And what that is really doing, is that:
`if operator != "+" or 45 or 42 or 47:` (ASCII representation of these characters)
What this means, is that the condition is true no matter what, because `or n` where N is not 0, would pass any time.

You want:
`if operator != "+" and operator != "-" and operator != "*" and operator != "/":`
You want an AND gate.

Also, I noticed you are saying `no1 = input(...)` then doing `int(num1)` instead of `int(no1)`.

As for jumping back to input, you use `continue`
Final code:

```
while True:

    operator = input("Give me an operator or \"exit\" to stop : ")
    if operator == "exit":
        break
    if operator not in [ "+", "-", "*" , "/"]: # credit to Florian Bernard for this line :)
        print ("You must enter an operator")
        continue

    num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter a number: ")
    if operator == "+":
        output = int(num1) + int(num2)
    elif operator == "-":
        output = int(num1) - int(num2)
    elif operator == "*":
        output = int(num1) * int(num2)
    else:
        output = int(num1) / int(num2)
    print("The result is " + str(output)) # this was previously str(result) but result is was not defined
print("See you soon!")
```

BUT! if you are feeling new today, you can use the **walrus operator** introduced in [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) and available from [python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)

```
while (operator := input("Give me an operator or \"exit\" to stop : ")) != "exit":
    if operator not in [ "+", "-", "*" , "/"]: # credit to Florian Bernard for this line :)
        print ("You must enter an operator")
        continue

    num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter a number: ")
    if operator == "+":
        output = int(num1) + int(num2)
    elif operator == "-":
        output = int(num1) - int(num2)
    elif operator == "*":
        output = int(num1) * int(num2)
    else:
        output = int(num1) / int(num2)
    print("The result is " + str(output))
print("See you soon!")
```

EDIT:
Edited the final code to use `continue`, previous version was.
Also added a python 3.8 implementation.

EDIT2:
Just correcting some stuff, making sentences truer.

Comment: And what do I need to do so that when it asks for a number and it's given a letter or an operator it will say "You must enter a number" and it goes back to asking for a number?

Comment: @RayCactus to continue the loop, skipping all of the code, use the keyword `continue`. I advise you to read my whole answer again, I made some changes...

Comment: @RayCactus also, look at Florian Bernard's answer for checking if the input is not an operator (the `not in [...]` part), I like it very much, better than using AND